# Swift can't fixed navigation bar for UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I am trying  to display a fix navigation bar for my UiTableViewController, I have a first ViewController and when I click on it, this will open my UITableViewController Here is the code of the click :

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewController") as! MyTableViewController
        vc.myObject = object // I pass some data
        presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

the UItableView is correctly display but not navigation bar appear, if I add one, the navigation bar scroll with the table view and I don't want this behavior.

I tried this without success :

> Go to the Editor menu, and click on the Embed In submenu, and choose
>   Navigation Controller

And tried to change some settings here :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way:

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewController") as! MyTableViewController
vc.myObject = object // I pass some data
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you explain me the difference please ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in your case you want to show navigation and for navigation you have to push your view controller to a `UINavigationController` thats why the solution is :

```
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTableViewController") as! MyTableViewController
vc.myObject = object // I pass some data
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

`presentViewController` offers a mechanism to display a modal view controller; i.e., a view controller that will take full control of your UI by being superimposed on top of a parent controller & establish a parent child relation b/w presenting & presented view controllers.

where as

`pushViewController` offers a much more flexible navigation process where you can push & pop a new controller to `UINavigationController`, so to go back to the previous one, in a ordered way. Imagine that controllers in a navigation controller will just build a sequence from left to right like building a stack of view controllers stacking upon each other.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation :)